# Re-axis the Matplotlib plot interval with np.arange does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot (left hand one) which y axis has 10 values. I try to re-axis from the default which is 0-9, interval = 2 to be 1-10, interval = 1. Normally, I use np.arange which works well except this one.

(default)

[image]

I ran

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 9, 2), np.arange(1, 10, 1))
```

and

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 2), np.arange(1, 11, 1))
```

and many another number, they did not work. Both of the above `.ytick` show

[image]

Why the interval does not change to 1? How to fix this?

Comment: The two arguments passed to ``yticks`` have different length, I'm assuming that it's just taking the first five elements of your second array.

Comment: @nicoguaro I also guess it is about length. But Y-axis has 10 values, 0-9 or 0-10 should work. I also tried many lengths, they did not work. I probably miss something here.

Comment: Then why not change the 2 in the first `arange`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the ticks as [0,1,2,...,9] and the ticklabels to your liking, e.g. [1,2,3,..,10].

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10), np.arange(1, 11))
```